# Is it correct to use "immigrate" for cities too?

Tags: meaning

I read before **immigrate** is used for countries. Is it correct? Can you say that you immigrated from one city to another? For example:

> I immigrated from Miami to Orlando two years ago.

Comment: You were too quick to accept the first answer anyone gave you. It is incorrect.  Immigrate (when used with people) can only mean to move permanently from your native country to another one.  Even though the dictionary definition seems to contradict this, a look at the full definition in the link refers to a Usage Note, which explains this.  Scientists can use immigrate in regard to animals and plants, which don't care about political boundaries, but this use is very specific to science, and probably not what you're asking about.  No one immigrates from Miami to Orlando; they move there.

Comment: @StevenLittman actually I get the same meaning as you said.

Comment: @StevenLittman - I disagree.

Comment: As I understand from all answers,"immigrate" uses for countries,but I'm a little confused,I'm not 100% sure what is correct !

Comment: @NiMa In your example, both "move" and "relocate" would work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some definitions from dictionary.com:

> [Migrate:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/migrate) to go from one country, region, or place to another. Synonyms: *move, resettle, relocate*.
>   [Immigrate:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/immigrate) to come to a country of which one is not a native, usually for permanent residence.

The term *immigrate* has taken on a technical meaning related to individual countries. For example, the [USCIS](http://www.uscis.gov/), standing for *U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services*, describes itself as [the government agency that oversees lawful immigration to the United States](http://www.uscis.gov/aboutus). As another example, if you said that you were an *immigrant* to Orlando, people might ask which country you came from and would likely not expect the reply of Miami. In that context, *migrate* and *migration services* also acquires the same technical meaning as *immigrate* despite more generic usage in other contexts.

This is similar to the use of the word *president* and its related word *preside*. You might say that [Buddy Dyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_Dyer) *presides* as mayor of Orlando, but I doubt that Americans would call Buddy Dyer a *president* because the word *president* has a technical meaning in politics and refers to the leader of the country as a whole.

So to answer your question, the word *immigrate* is used for movements between countries, not cities within a country.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct. People *emigrate* from one country or region to another, not between cities.

Consider using ***move*** or ***relocate*** instead.

> relocate
>
> 1. *v.t.* to move to a different location.
> 2. *v.i.* to change one's residence or place of business; move.
>    [1825–35, Amer.] [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/relocate)

And so,

> *I **immigrated** from India to the US six years ago*.

But

> *I **moved/relocated** from Miami to Orlando two years ago*.

Comment: Your answer *"no"* is correct, but your reasoning is totally wrong. You can *migrate* into a city, but *immigration* general means crossing a political boundary. [See this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=migrated+to+Chicago%2Cmigrated+to+the+Midwest%2C+migrated+to+Illinois&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmigrated%20to%20Chicago%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmigrated%20to%20the%20Midwest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmigrated%20to%20Illinois%3B%2Cc0). Chicago is a city, Illinois is a state, the Midwest is a region, and there's not much difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be used also referring regions/places within the same country, though I'd probably say: "I moved from Miami to Orlando two years ago:"

***[Immigrate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/immigrate):***

> - To enter and settle in a country or region to which one is not native.
> - ***Immigrate***  describes the move relative to the destination: The promise of prosperity here in the United States encouraged many people to immigrate.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: One could use it figuratively to create emphasis or irony. *I decided I had become too old for life in London so I emigrated to Derbyshire*.

Comment: @WS2 Different **world**.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia says-

> Immigration is the movement of people into a destination country to which they are not native or do not possess its citizenship in order to settle or reside there, especially as permanent residents or naturalized citizens, or to take-up employment as a migrant worker or temporarily as a foreign worker.

Notice it say **country**.

So no, it is only for countries, not for cities.

Answer (score 0):

Are we being prescriptive or descriptive here? For the last 30 years or so "immigrate" has been used in connection with cities, at least in some cases.[image: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?]
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=immigrate+to+the+city&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimmigrate%20to%20the%20city%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score -1):

Yes,it can definitely be used.In our day to day life, it has been associated closely with the movement from one country to another.But it applies for movement between cities too.

Definition from wordweb:
Migrate to a new environment

Comment: Welcome to ELU. We prefer answers which show corroboration rather than answers which simply look like opinion.

Comment: I agree.  I've seen it used, eg, in referring to people migrating between regions of the US, particularly prior to about 1950.  The significant factor, I suspect, is that the individuals are moving between distinctly different cultures.